# Windows 10 UWP - Programatically detect change in developer features

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-desktop

We have a use case in which we want to monitor some windows devices remotely.
In Windows 10 mobile *OS Settings > Update & Security > For developers* there are three options:

1. Use developer features.
2. Device discovery.
3. Device Portal

We want to detect any change in above three settings through a UWP app. I searched a lot but couldn't find a way to do this. I am also open to periodically check the settings and detect a change if its possible.

Note: This app is not a windows store app, it is for our internal use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the developer features you can [use registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development) to poll the current setting:

**Sideloading of apps**

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock\AllowAllTrustedApps
```

**Developer mode**

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock\AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense
```

For Device discovery and Device Portal I haven't been able to find a solution unfortunately. It is possible that these are also somehow configurable through registry, but I haven't found the keys so far.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for replying. I may be misunderstanding your response, but I searched on how to read registry using UWP app and I can across many posts suggesting its not possible. Can you please provide some examples? Or a link with documentation?

Comment: You mentioned this is not a Windows Store app, but an internal app. If it is not a Windows Store app, you can use Windows Runtime brokered components, which allow you to communicate with a full .NET Framework library from a UWP app. This way you can use the full framework including registry access or other advanced features. You can find more info about Brokered Components here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps

Comment: Thanks this was helpful.